# arraylist not updating outside the onNext method

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

ArrayList updated in onNext but outside it ArrayList is not updated.

```
    mListItems.clear(); //size = 0

    compositeDisposable.add(Observable.create(handler)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnNext(category -> {
                mListItems.add(category); //size = 3
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            })
            .subscribe());

    mListItems.forEach(this::expandAllParent); //size = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because that block of `RxJava` code runs `asynchronously` because you are subscribing to it on [IO](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/schedulers/Schedulers.html#io--) thread which means a thread other than android's main thread, so it is not guarantied that code inside `doOnNext` gets executed before code after your `RxJava` chain. I mean the execution order is like this:

```
mListItems.clear(); // -> first this line gets executed

// Here and observable gets created and passed to another thread to get execute by that thread
compositeDisposable.add(Observable.create(handler)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnNext(category -> {
        mListItems.add(category);
        notifyDataSetChanged(); // and at last this block of code gets executed
    })
    subscribe());

mListItems.forEach(this::expandAllParent); // -> secondly this line gets executed
```

if you want to execute `expandAllParent` correctly for all added items then its better to move that line of code inside `doOnNext` method, like this:
    mListItems.clear();

```
compositeDisposable.add(Observable.create(handler)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnNext(category -> {
        mListItems.add(category);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        mListItems.forEach(this::expandAllParent); // -> move this here
    })
    subscribe());
```

Comment: thanks but how can i get the list outside the doOnNext method, i've tried this earlier but its not working as expected.

Comment: Well, In case of I understood your problem correcty, if you want to access the items being added to `mListItems` after `doOnNext` and outside of it, then you have use those items after `doOnNext` gets executed which means at the end of the lambda function you are passing to `doOnNext`. There is no other way, Or if there is any, I am not aware of it :)

Comment: In `doOnNext`, you are on the main thread with the `category` available. You could simply call `expandAllParent(category)` without adding them all to a list. If you still need the whole list further on, add an `onComplete` handler to `subscribe` and work with `mListItems` there.